# Regarding memory size, cleaning up objects

Tags: c#

Consider an example as below

```
class B
{
   int x;
}

class A
{
     int a;
     int b;
     B b1 = new B();

     void testMethod()
     {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            b1 = new B();
     }
}

class MainClass //Will never close this application
{
    static void Main(object[] args)
    {
        A a1 = new A();
        a1.testMethod();
    }
}
```

In this above example am creating a new Class B object everytime in the loop. So here my question is when i assign a new object to b1, what will happen to the previous object will that be cleaned up or will it remain up memory.

If it is not cleaning up and increasing the memory, how to clean up?

Comment: It will be garbage collected since the previous object is no longer being referenced.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you create a new object of `B`

```
b1 = new B();
```

the original object stored in `b1` becomes inaccessible. This means that it is eligible for garbage collection. This does ***not*** mean that it will be cleaned from memory immediately though!

Objects that are eligible for GC will be actually GC'ed  at "some time in the future". We don't know and don't need to know what time exactly. Just trust  the GC.

In other words, after you run your `testMethod`, 9 objects of `B` will be eligible for GC or has already been collected, while the tenth object will remain stored in the variable `b1`.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you do this:  `b1= new B();`, you are assigning to `b1` a new reference to a new object (`b1` is **not** a [ValueType](http://net-informations.com/faq/general/valuetype-referencetype.htm)), so, the previous reference is now unused, thus, the Garbage Collector is going to dispose it.

Summarizing: is not increasing the memory, because it is a [**Managed Resource**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/memory-management-and-gc)

Answer (score 0):

Life of any value type and reference type is depend on access specifier used to defined it and scope of that functionality. Functionality can be any class, function or loop where you defined your object.

In your case you defined reference type `B b1 = new B()` with out any access specifier (default access specifier) so it will be considered as [internal](http://www.completecsharptutorial.com/basic/internal/). variable defined with internal can not be accessible to outside world.

Scope of  `b1` is limited to for loop which you defined your code.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            b1 = new B();
```

If you notice above two conditions, you will understand **object `b1` is disposed by [garbage collector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals) after each iteration of for loop**.

Comment: What if after the for loop i have one more statement using b1

       b1.Dosomthing();

then when it will be garbage collected.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, **answer is b1 will be disposed by garbage collector at the end of class A**. To demonstrate I tried example please look into it. Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nhea0e